# Small Buffer Optimization and alignment

Tags: c++, c++11

I am writing a *C++* wrapper around a legacy API. This API provides me with a pointer value to keep extra data, and I want to implement the *Small Buffer Optimization* with it.

I have implemented an `is_small_pod` *metafunction* that checks whether a given type is *POD* and it fits within a `void*`:

```
template< typename Type >
struct is_small_pod
  : std::integral_constant<
        bool
      , std::is_pod< Type >::type::value
        && sizeof( Type ) <= sizeof( void* )
    >
{};
```

and I'm setting the value like this:

```
// void*& param;
if( detail::is_small_pod< Type >() )
{
    *static_cast< Type* >( &param ) = value;
} else {
    param = new Type( value );
}
```

Am I implementing this optimization correctly? I believe this will fail when the value alignment is not compatible with the *alignment* of a pointer (odd corner case as it may be). Is that situation even possible, or am I just overthinking it? How should I extend my *metafunction* to check for compatible *alignment* as well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible for the alignment of a type to be greater than the size of that type.

> #### 3.11 Alignment [basic.align]
>
> [...] An *alignment* is an implementation-deﬁned integer value representing the number of bytes between successive addresses at which a given object can be allocated.
>
> #### 5.3.3 Sizeof [expr.sizeof]
>
> 2 - [...] the size of an array of *n* elements is *n* times the size of an element.

So, your code can only break if `alignof(void *) < sizeof(void *)`, which is not the case on most platforms.

For safety, you can write:

```
template< typename Type >
struct is_small_pod
  : std::integral_constant<
        bool
      , std::is_pod< Type >::type::value
        && sizeof( Type ) <= sizeof( void* )
        && alignof( Type ) <= alignof( void* )
    >
{};
```

Comment: While technically correct, this does ignore everyday things like 16-byte alignment requirements for SSE* support.

Comment: @ildjarn for SSE you generally tend to use `__m128` etc., which is 16 bytes in size and in alignment.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a general approach, you can always try testing your theories.  I imagine you would do something like this:

```
template< class Type >
bool TestAlignmentSanity( Type value )
{
    // This function is only valid for small POD types
    if( !detail::is_small_pod< Type >() )
        return false;

    // Temporary space covering alignments spanning the size of a void*
    const int nBytes = sizeof(void*);
    char buffer[sizeof(Type) + nBytes - 1];

    // For each target alignment, test that a copy is successful.
    for( int i = 0; i < nBytes; i++ )
    {
       Type * target = static_cast< Type* >( &buffer[i] );

       // Sanity-check that the pointer was actually aligned as we requested
       if( (char*)target != &buffer[i] ) return false;

       // Copy and test that the result is as expected.  Assumes '==' operator
       // is defined...  Otherwise, implement with byte comparisons.
       *target = value;
       if( !(*target == value) ) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Here I tested that the data type can be copied into any alignment that spans the size of a `void*`.  It's just a thought. =)